# return type and array size assigning question

Tags: c, cs50

I am now trying to change the return type of function encrypt to char (or string if necessary) instead of void. Although this code already works (and btw, I have two other versions of code that works too) I really want to grasp the fundamental concept of how return type works and so on. Also, I'm wondering how line 33 `char *ciphertext = plaintext;` can be modified in a way that the array does not hold any address or values (if, for example, drops the pointer(*)) but assign the size like `char *ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)]`? This is not a necessary modification needed since the code works totally fine, but if I use this kind of style, and in a given situation where I need to store massive volume of data into the array, it will slow down the speed.

So, that was exhaustive. To make it simple, here are the two questions:

1. How can I modify the function encrypt return type to char or string?
2. How can array ciphertext get initialized with assigned size identical to the plaintext while data(value) is not stored?

I deeply appreciate your help, answer, comment (feel free to criticize if the style of my code isn't clean or pleasant to read).

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Trying char as a return type
void encrypt(char *plaintext, int k, char *ciphertext);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Validate if the user inputted the adequate value type
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Loop for validating if each char of argv is a digit
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        // if the key is not a digit, it will return 0.
        if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // function atoi converts key(array of char) into an integer
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    char *plaintext = get_string("plaintext:  ");
    char *ciphertext = plaintext;
    encrypt(plaintext, key, ciphertext);
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    return 0;
}

void encrypt(char *plaintext, int k, char *ciphertext)
{
    while (*plaintext) {
        // Identify if the value is an alphabet
        if (isalpha(*plaintext) != 0)
        {
            // Apply formula to uppercase character
            if (isupper(*plaintext) != 0)
            {
                *ciphertext = ((*plaintext - 'A' + k) % 26) + 'A';
            }
            // Apply formula to lowercase character
            else
            {
                *ciphertext = ((*plaintext - 'a' + k) % 26) + 'a';
            }
        }
        plaintext++;
        ciphertext++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char *ciphertext = NULL;` You can't write to a NULL pointer.

Comment: `ciphertext` is `NULL`, so accessing it via the `*` or `[]` operators is illegal and will likely lead to a segmentation violation.

Comment: You probably want to return a `char *` (which cs50 aliases to `string`) from `encrypt`. That's a string that you can print with `%s`. In `encrypt` allocate enough memory to hold the encrypted string: `strlen(text) + 1` for the null terminator.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question does not show signs the poster has done elementary debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are writing to a NULL pointer since you set `ciphertext` to NULL. What you want to do is allocate memory for `ciphertext`. This can be done with `char *ciphertext = strdup(text);` which sets up `ciphertext` with a newly allocated pointer to a copy of the null-terminated char pointer named `text`. Using either this solution or the one below, you don't need to `// Store non-alphabetical value as it is` since that value is already there.

Using `strdup()` is one method, but there is a better option if you can modify `text` itself. You can simply use:

```
void encrypt(char *text, int k) {
    while (*text) {
        // Identify if the value is an alphabet
        if (isalpha(*text) != 0) {
            if (isupper(*text) != 0) {
                // Apply formula to uppercase character
                *text = ((*text - 'A' + k) % 26) + 'A';
            } else {
                // Apply formula to lowercase character
                *text = ((*text - 'a' + k) % 26) + 'a';
            }
        }
        text++;
    }
}
```

A little explanation: `while (*text)` means do the following until the value stored ***at*** text is 0. `text++;` increments the pointer. So after that line `text` is pointing to the next char. All that does is just another way of doing `for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)` but without needing a new variable.

Note that the above code no longer returns the result of the "encryption". Rather, it modifies the content of the `char *` you passed it. No memory allocation necessary-- the caller did it for you.

If you opt to use the above code, you'll need to do something like this to print the result:

```
...
char *text = get_string("plaintext:  \n");
encrypt(text, key);
printf("ciphertext: %s\n", text);
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I get why Null pointer is not accepted. I did make a slight modification in code to try out using a new variable called ciphertext. Also, I am wondering if we can make the return type char (or string) instead of void for function encrypt? Do you have any recommendation on how I can modify the code? I edited my code and the question itself above.

Comment: @flyagain If `encrypt` were to return anything, it would be a `char *`. Based on your questions, you don't really understand what a pointer is. That's not a bad thing, you just need to learn. **Pointers are a critical part of C, and you NEED to understand them if you wish to learn the language.** I can't give a nice example in a comment, as it would be too long. I highly encourage you to look up some resources on pointers.

Comment: thanks for point it out. I will surely do that. Thanks!